# Linux minimal example C code with pipe redirection for IO

Tags: c, linux, pipe, io-redirection

I made a post on a question a few days ago that requested a more minimal example of code since I posted all my code in my complicated example.  I am posting that to show you but I realized in making the post that what's wrong is going to take myself time to debug on my own.  The problem I realized is not a fundamental or conceptual error but rather a bug that I need to use my own code debug methods to find (once I go back to it, taking a break for a little while!  I have no deadline -- just something I decided to do to expand my systems knowledge on my own.)  In my code, the pipe redirection works fine for this input code: ls -l | grep patternNameOfFileInDir but this does not work: ls -l | grep patternNameOfFileInDir > toOutputFile, yet this does work: ps > psOutputFile, so you can see that it's an exercise in code debug, not conceptual or fundamental in error.  But here is the minimal example that you requested.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAX_COUNT 10 // 10 child processes max per command line

static char line [80];
static char *token;
static int commands, pipecount;

while (1) {

  int i;
  int fd[MAX_COUNT][2]; 
  int pid[MAX_COUNT];

  putchar ('>'); // the shell prompt

  // wait for input -- will use a read() syscall on STDIN_FILENO
  readline (line); 

 // parse command line, count commands, args and shell characters
 token = strtok (line, " "); // repeat as necessary

 commands = ...; // number of commands counted
 pipecount = ...; // number of pipes

 /* Note: really need to know where pipes and shell characters are in the
 line input. */

 /* Create up to pipecount pipes */
 for (i = 0; i < pipecount; i++) 
    pipe (fd[i]);

 for (i = 0; i < commands; i++) {

     if ((pid[i] = fork ()) == 0) { // child

       if (i == 0) { // first command

          // redirect stdout to pipe input
          if (pipecount) {
             dup2 (fd[i][1], STDOUT_FILENO);
             close (fd[i][0]);

         // Close all other unused pipe fds
         }
       }
       else if (i == commands - 1) { // last command

       // redirect pipe output to stdin
       if (pipecount) {
           dup2 (fd[i-1][0], STDIN_FILENO);
           close (fd[i-1][1]);

           // Close all other unused pipe fds
       }
     }
     else { // nested command

        // redirect both stdout and stdin
        if (pipecount) {
          dup2 (fd[i-1][0], STDIN_FILENO);
          dup2 (fd[i][1], STDOUT_FILENO);
          close (fd[i-1][1]);
          close (fd[i][0]);     

        // Close all other unused pipe fds
        }
     }

     // execute command in child -- don't close fds on exec
     execve (token, argv, envp); 
 }

 // Here, you really need to be more careful about where in the
 // shell command sequence pipes are used 
 pipecount--;

 if (!pipecount) 
   // Close all pipe fds in parent
}

// Suspend shell while child processes are running 
// Only do this if not backgrounded command string
for (i = 0; i < commands; i++)
    waitpid (pid[i]);

}
```

Comment: Either update your existing question with the code, or if you have another but related question then add a link to the original question.

Comment: There needs to be a question in your post. What is your question?

Comment: The question I had was why the test case where I send the output to an outfile is broken when I pipe from one command to the next command.  When I pipe from one command to another and send it to stdout, it works fine.  A few days ago I submitted a much longer code submission and this is a reduced one.  If anyone has advice that would be helpful.  If not, I'll go back and debug this at a later date, since it partially works.